# Error while installing Ubuntu server

Tags: server

When I try to install Ubuntu server on my pc it shows the below error
"'(initramfs) file system layers are missing:\n '/cdrom/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs' doesn't exist.)"'

Comment: The ISO you're using is incomplete or corrupt.  Redownload the ISO and verify its hash sums. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu